# "Input Not Supported" on Acer S241HL Monitor with HDMI after Windows 10 Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-10-v1709

My HP PC recently installed Windows 10 version 1709 (Fall Creators Update). After the update, my second monitor, which is connected via HDMI, will no longer work with Windows. When the PC starts up, the HP logo shows on both monitors, but, once Windows loads, the second monitor goes black with a blue moving rectangle that states "Input Not Supported". I tried uninstalling the update, and the second monitor worked fine. However, Windows forced the update again. I know there are workarounds for preventing the update, however, I would rather get to the bottom of the issue with the monitor. The first monitor is connected via VGA.

My setup:

- HP Slimline Desktop PC 270-p0xx
- Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700T CPU @ 2.90GHz
- Installed RAM: 8.00 GB
- System Type: 64-bit operating
  system, x64-based processor

Windows:

- Edition: Windows 10 Home
- Version: 1709
- OS Build: 16299.125

Monitors:

- Acer S241HL (both the same)

Comment: This sounds like a display driver issue, and your refresh rate solution, just masks the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on Microsoft's Answers site:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/windows-10-upgrade-gives-input-not-supported-error/124b82f1-8917-4d0e-a783-54f2ca1ff8d1

In short, I changed the Refresh Rate in Control Panel > Intel Graphics Settings > Display to "50p Hz" for the second display. I just kept trying different Refresh Rates until one showed the display and looked good. "50p Hz" looks the best.

Comment: Would love to know why this was down-voted when this solution actually fixed my problem....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading today.  The error affected only the external display for my laptop. Microsoft Support took over my PC and after a rather long trial and error session came up with a solution:  Upgrade the graphics driver(s) to the latest version:

Device manager -> Display adapters -> (select adapter) -> Update -> Online search

Display:  Acer S240HL.
Adapters: Intel UHD Graphics 620 and NVIDA GeForce 940MX
I am uncertain if they updated one or both.

Comment: I tried that but after multiple attempts via Windows Update and Acer's website, it was determined that my driver was up-to-date. The accepted answer worked (update the Refresh Rate in Intel Graphics Settings).

Answer (score 0):

My second monitor had the same problem.  I disconnected both monitors.  I swapped the cables. I used cable (connected with HDMI adaptor) to plug in my main monitor. Restarted the computer. Turned it off.  Connected the second monitor through the original cable of the main monitor which was connected through DVI.  Turned on the computer and both screens work now.